# oledb vs excel interop vs open xml vs data access controls for reading large excel data in .net

Tags: .net, excel, vsto, openxml

I need to process large excel file (300-500 MB). I need to convert it to XML file (of similar size).

In the excel i just need to read the data in single forward only way. Support for XLS and XLSX is required. Performance is critical.

I am confused between following options
1. [Excel Interop](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel): Requires office components in client machine. Hence not recommended.
2. [Ole DB](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2010/03/29/retrieving-data-from-excel/): Just checked it loads entire file in memory. So does not sound good to me.
3. [Open XML](http://openxmldeveloper.org/): Does not support XLS file format

Please suggest the other better alternatives and comparitive analysis of above approaches. (To read large excel file xls/xlsx format in forward only manner)

Comment: Would it be possible to convert your .xls files to .xlsx beforehand?  It sounds like OpenXML would be your best bet, if not for its incompatibility with .xls

Comment: compatibility is required :(

Comment: Just found this, but I've never used it.  Maybe check it out, it seems to be compatible with .xls and .xlsx: http://code.google.com/p/npoi/

Comment: possible duplicate of [OLE DB vs OPEN XML SDK vs Excel.interop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365434/ole-db-vs-open-xml-sdk-vs-excel-interop)