# Linking Excel In C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2015

So I'm working in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and want to be able to link the project to a Excel Spreadsheet.

What I want to achieve is this; simply be able to create a program where I can use the number in a specific cell and then do some calculations with it. As an example, take cell D4 and then create a poisson distribution using the value as the mean.

Comment: - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/302084
- http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-tutorial.htm

Comment: Ask your favorite search engine. Keywords are "c# excel" and/or "c# office interop"

Comment: you can use openXml [link] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) which does not require any license. If you use excel Interop it requires license to use it on client machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a reference to Microsoft.Office.Core and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in the projects References.
Then add the references to your class.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Then you can open/create/manipulate excel sheets in your code. lots of info for that on the web.

Update to comment--

This example is opening a new worksheet to save when done.

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook myWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet myWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
myWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
myWorkSheet =  (Excel.Worksheet)myWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```

Done some work on the sheet

```
myWorkSheet.Cells[curXLRow, 5] = "PF";
myWorkSheet.Cells[curXLRow, 6] = "PA";
```

Then Save the file

```
string fileName = "C:\\MyFileName.xlsx";
myWorkBook.SaveAs(fileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
myWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();

releaseObject(myWorkSheet);
releaseObject(myWorkBook);
releaseObject(xlApp);
```

Hope this helps. I dont have an example to open an existing excel file. But look up:

```
xlApp.Workbooks.Open(lots of parameters...);
```

Comment: i used this but confused to what I put in the area marked                                                                                                      Excel.Worksheet excelSheet = WHAT DO I PUT HERE
            Excel.Range rng = (Excel.Range)excelSheet.Cells[10, 10];

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested, it is recommended to use [Open XML SDK 2.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), rather than `Interop`. The reasons are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365434/ole-db-vs-open-xml-sdk-vs-excel-interop).

Getting started with EPPlus is very easy as shown [here](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ContentSheetExample) in a few examples:

- open the Excel file using FileInfo
- create a ExcelPacakge from it
- get worksheet reference from Workbook.Worksheets["WorksheetName"]
- use worksheet reference to read and write cell values and formulas and much more