# How to get the Data in right format When reading an Excel file from FTP Server

Tags: c#, excel, ftp

I am trying to read an excel file from an FTP Server and store the datas in a list.
Excel file is reading from an FTP Server but data is coming

This is my code

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Listing all files from a folder

        string filename = getFileList("ftp://ftp.demosite.com/demoFolder/", "username", "password");


        //Here we know the file name
        FtpWebRequest reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.demosite.com/demoFolder/"+filename);
        reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
        reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
        reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password"); 
        reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        reqFTP.Proxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        // for excelread
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        string[] allLines = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        // for textfile read
        //TextReader tmpReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream);
        //string fileContents = tmpReader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine("Now writing from file....");
        foreach (var item in allLines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);                
        }
        Console.WriteLine("all file content is printed....");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

and the data is coming in this format:
[Current O/P Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRNjh.png)

Please Help!
Thank You.

Comment: Is the file a `.xls` file? Because that's a binary format. Even if it's `.xlsx` just splitting into lines isn't work.

Comment: Yup this is a .xls file.

Comment: @stuartd tell me how to get the data in correct format

Comment: You're going to need to read it using Excel or NPOI or something similar - what you're seeing is essentially what you get when you open a xls file in Notepad

Comment: that's right..So do i need to install that EXCEL or NPOI from nuget package mgr. and pass that StreamReader object?

Comment: Maybe try reading the documentation? And i don't think Excel is on nuget.

Comment: Okay @stuartd Thanks man :)

Comment: Use BinaryReader like this : 
            const int BUFFER_SIZE = 40;
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(responseStream);
            string data = string.Join("", reader.ReadBytes(BUFFER_SIZE).Select(x => x.ToString("2x")));

Comment: okay @jdweng can you tell what i'll put in place of "2x"

Comment: Sorry about typo.  Should be "x2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stuartd pointed out. You are reading an excel file as a text file. If you want to read an excel file you need to add the Office.Interop.Excel references to the project and then to your classes. If you have excel on your machine you can do this without a problem. If you do not have excel you will have to find a third party library. I recently posted an answer explaining how to do this if excel is on your machine.

[Linking Excel In C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39637234/linking-excel-in-c-sharp/39637635#39637635)

Once the reference is there you can access excel files properly.

Comment: Assuming you are using an IDE. You first need to add the reference to your project. Right click on the project and add a reference under the COM section and look for Microsoft Excel Object Library. This will add the Office.Core and Interop.Excel references to your project. To use these library's in your classes...add a "using" statement to access the library. Then The class can open/create Excel files and do things like myWorkSheet.Cells[ARow, ACol] = "PF". That info can be found in the above link. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you do not have Excel on your machine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654932/create-excel-files-from-c-sharp-without-office gives some options.