# Set word document properties programmatically from c#

Tags: c#, .net, properties, openxml

I'm trying to set the the Paper source of an existing `.docx` file from my `C#` code. I don't know if
1. Word is installed on the computer,
2. Word format is `OpenXML` or not (that depend's on the computer's installation as far as I understood).

I've found two approaches :
- using `Interop` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects), with [following properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.pagesetup_members.aspx),
- using `OpenXML` as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh674468.aspx).

I am unsure about which way to go and if this will result in a "stable" solution, in the sense that it is not sensitive the configuration of the machine on which the code is executed (is Word installed or not, which version, which configuration, ...).

Which way should I go and what limitations will I have?

Comment: see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365434/ole-db-vs-open-xml-sdk-vs-excel-interop

Answer (score -1):

I ended using OpenXML sdk which works great. It will work but do mot forget to deploy the dll (un case the OpenXML framework is mot installed on the client computer).